# Test right time in alarm

Tags: iphone, xcode, alarm

Sorry google translate make mistake, to many mistake,

i want make an alarm in Xcode, but i ave a problem, everythings  work fine if i use a picker view with date and time, but if i switch the picker view in one with only time, it's impossible set the alarm, because if i set the alarm at a time before now ring immediately,

how can i do for solve without use a picker view with date?

This is the action that set the alarm.

PS sorry for the previews message maybe my english is better then google translate...

```
  // Set Allarm Uno

-(IBAction)setAlarmUno:(id)sender{

NSLog(@"In Alarm Date");
NSDateFormatter *formatter =
[[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSLog(@"About to Set Date");
AlarmDateUno = [alarmDatePickerUno date];
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
isAlarmUnoOn = 1;


// Setta la label della data con l'orario

NSString *notifyTime = [[NSString alloc]initWithString:[formatter stringFromDate:AlarmDateUno]];
NSMutableString *alarmString = [[NSMutableString alloc]initWithString:@""];
NSString *temp = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:[formatter stringFromDate:AlarmDateUno]];
[alarmString appendString:temp];
[LabelalarmUno setText:alarmString];


    if(clicked == 0) 
        {            
            clicked =1;
            [btOnOffUno  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OnBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                bellOne.hidden = NO;

             }

    else 
        { 
            clicked = 0;
            [btOnOffUno  setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"OffBtn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                bellOne.hidden = YES; 
                isAlarmUnoOn = 0;
```

For pooling time after set alarm i use this:

```
   // CONTROLLO TEMPO UNO

   - (void)runTimerUno {

            myTickerUno = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 0.5
                                            target: self
                                          selector: @selector(showActivityUno)
                                          userInfo: nil
                                           repeats: YES];

     }

  - (void)showActivityUno {
  NSDateFormatter *formatter =
        [[[NSDateFormatter alloc] init] autorelease];
NSDate *date = [NSDate date];

if(isAlarmUnoOn == 1 && AlarmUnoPlaying ==0){
    NSLog(@"Going to compare times Uno");
    NSDate *d = [date earlierDate:AlarmDateUno];
    NSLog(@"Compared Times Uno");


    if (d == date) {
        NSLog(@"Current time earlier Uno");
    } 
    else if (d == AlarmDateUno) {
        AlarmUnoPlaying = 1;

        [self playAlarmSoundUno];
    }               

}
[formatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterMediumStyle];
```

}

I try to integrate your code in mine without success.

Comment: Please use proper English. I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: Sorry google translate make mistake, to many mistake,

i want make an alarm in Xcode, but i ave a problem, everythings  work fine if i use a picker view with date and time, but if i switch the picker view in one with only time, it's impossible set the alarm, because if i set the alarm at a time before now ring immediately, 

how can i do for solve without use a picker view with date?

This is the action that set the alarm.


PS sorry for the previews message maybe my english is better then google translate...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will add the time from the picker to the current date, and then add one day if the time is in the past so that the alarm is always in the future:

```
AlarmDateUno                = [alarmDatePickerUno date];
NSCalendar *currentCalendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar]; 

// Get the current date & time, and modify it to the beginning of the day (midnight).
NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];
NSDateComponents *currentDateComponents = [currentCalendar components: NSDayCalendarUnit | NSMonthCalendarUnit | NSYearCalendarUnit fromDate:currentDate];
currentDate = [currentCalendar dateFromComponents:currentDateComponents];

// Add the time  from the picker to the currentDate (midnight value) to give us today's date with the picker time.
AlarmDateUno = [currentDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:[AlarmDateUno timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate]];

// Now, if AlarmDateUno is before the current time, assume that we mean tomorrow and add one day:
if ([currentDate compare:AlarmDateUno] == NSOrderedAscending) {
    // Add one day to the current alarm time.
    NSDateComponents *oneDay = [[NSDateComponents alloc] init];
    [oneDay setDay:1];
    AlarmDateUno = [currentCalendar dateByAddingComponents:oneDay toDate:AlarmDateUno options:0];
}
```

Comment: Yes is exactly what i mean... but i don't understand were i can use this portion of code? and what is "CurrentDate". Thanks for helping!

Comment: I modified the code from my original answer.  It should be what you are looking for!

Comment: the problem is that i use this to perform the alarm

Comment: At the end of this block of code, AlarmDateUno will be set to a specific date and time in the future.  Is this not what you need?

Comment: You should just be able to replace this line in your code:  `AlarmDateUno = [alarmDatePickerUno date];` with my code...